# Displaying an image over another

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

Currently I am having an issue whereby the Robot.png is replacing the image of my gameboard.png . I want to make it so that the robot .png is ontop of the board and be able to move the robot around the board.

Board.Java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

private Image gameboard;


public Board(){
    initBoard();
}

private void initBoard(){
    loadImage();

    int w = gameboard.getWidth(this);
    int h = gameboard.getHeight(this);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));

}

private void loadImage(){

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("res/gameboard.png");
    gameboard = i.getImage();



}   

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(gameboard,0,0,null);

}


}
```

Player.Java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends JPanel {

public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("res/Robot.png");
    Image image1 = ic.getImage();
    g2d.drawImage(image1, 100, 100, null);
}

}
```

GameGUI.Java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GameGui extends JFrame {

public GameGui(){

    initGui();

}

public void initGui(){

    add(new Board());
    add(new Player());
    setTitle("11+ Game");
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(1240,620);
}

}
```

Comment: Quit posting and deleting questions. I think this is the 3rd time you have posted this question. Ask a proper question with all the relevant information in the question. Then update the original question if you need to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload the robot image every time. You should use ImageIO to load it, and save it in a member variable.

Otherwise, the way to not have the image overwrite the whole background image is to use height and width parameters with your drawImage call

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("res/Robot.png");
    Image image1 = ic.getImage();
    int width = ..., height = ...;
    g2d.drawImage(image1, 100, 100, width, height, null);
}
```

Comment: 1. `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and 2. `JPanel` (`public class Player extends JPanel`) should be opaque (but not important somehow, maybe) and 3. `width, height, null);` can be  `width, height, this);`